# React Not Starting in DRF project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, django, npm, django-rest-framework

I am currently trying to create a react app in a django restframework project using `npm start` but I keep getting the following errors:

```
$ npm start

> ui@0.1.0 start C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Projects\Workout & Api\reacter\ui
> react-scripts start

'Api\reacter\ui\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Projects\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)   
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ui@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ui@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-09T14_21_33_819Z-debug.log
```

The thing is outside of the DRF project, `npm start` works just fine.

I have tried force cleaning my npm cache, deleted my npm cache and npm folder, deleted my node_modules folder, uninstalled and reinstalled nodejs, added c:program/win32 to path but nothing has worked.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: can you share your frontend code?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i finally figured it out. Turns out having the "&" symbol in my path was the problem.@pplonski